# Adafruit raspberry-pi neopixel library throws error "ImportError: No module named _rpi_ws281x"

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi, adafruit

I ran into this problem when following the Adafruit Neopixel tutorial:
https://learn.adafruit.com/neopixels-on-raspberry-pi/python-usage

I double checked having all the requirements installed but still got an error:

> ImportError: No module named _rpi_ws281x

It took me quite a while to piece the solution together that's why I wanted to document it here. See answer below.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to rebuild and reinstall the rpi_ws281x library from the source (as suggested in various github issues e.g. https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x/issues/225)

Let's walk through this:

I'm assuming you followed the Adafruit Neopixel tutorial and have installed all the relevant python3 stuff, especially the setup tools.

We will need a couple of additional dependencies installed on your pi to build the library.

> sudo apt-get install python-dev git scons swig

Clone the rpi_ws281x repository

> git clone https://github.com/jgarff/rpi_ws281x.git

and change into the rpi_ws281x directory

> cd rpi_ws281x

Next let's build the C library

> sudo scons

Now change into the library's python directory

> cd python

Build the python module (remember to use python3)

> sudo python3 setup.py build

And install it

> sudo python3 setup.py install

That's it! The error should be gone.

Comment: I get the following error on this step: `ImportError: cannot import name 'log' from 'distutils'`

Answer (score 1):

I was going through the same tutorial as you, however had to remove and re-install rpi_ws281x to get it to work.

```
sudo pip3 uninstall rpi_ws281x

sudo pip3 install rpi_ws281x
```

Seeing you specifically use "python3" tipped me off to use pip3...